# firebase security rules all auth users can add a new post and only user who created his post can edit it

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am currently working on a page where all auth users can create a post. The post should also be editable, but only by the creator. Also an admin with a certain email address should be able to edit the post.

This are my security roles:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "shoes" : {
      ".read": true,
        "$shoeID" : {
          ".write" : "root.child('shoes').child($shoeID).child('postowner').val() === auth.uid && auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('uid').val() === auth.uid || auth.token.email === 'admin@admin.com'"
        }
    },
    "websites" : {
      ".read": true,
        "$shoeID" : {
          "$storeID" : {
             ".write" : "root.child('websites').child($shoeID).child($storeID).child('postowner').val() === auth.uid && auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('uid').val() === auth.uid || auth.token.email === 'admin@admin.com'" 
          }
        }
    },
    "users" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read" : "auth != null && root.child('users').child($uid).child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

and this is my database structure:

[image]

I think I am doing something wrong, because with my current rules any user can change the data.

Comment: Unlikely to be the cause of the problem, but the `root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('uid').val() === auth.uid ` in the write rule for a show seems like a noop to me. If you want to enforce that integrity, you only need to so in write operations to `/users/$uid` not in each individual shoe write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the problem comes from, but this rule seems overly complicated to me:

```
".write" : "
  root.child('shoes').child($shoeID).child('postowner').val() === auth.uid 
  && auth != null 
  && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('uid').val() === auth.uid 
  || auth.token.email === 'admin@admin.com'
"
```

Things that can be improved:

- There is no need to check `auth != null` **after** you've already used `auth.uid`. Either move the null check first, or skip it altogether.
- There is no need to look up the shoe by `$shoeID`, as it's already in `data`. So your `root.child('shoes').child($shoeID)` is equivalent to the (shorter and more idiomatic) `data`.
- The `root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('uid').val() === auth.uid`  clause seems meaningless in write operations of shoes. This clause should only be enforced in the write operation of `/users/$user`.

With these changes your rules become:

```
".write" : "
  data.child('postowner').val() === auth.uid 
  || auth.token.email === 'admin@admin.com'
"
```

As said: I don't see what's going wrong in the write operation, but hopefully thee simpler rules make it easier to troubleshoot that problem. I'd recommend starting in the rules playground, and using that to replay what your code does.

Comment: i have shortened my rules as you have described. However, if I use only this rule as a test purpose: data.child('postowner').val() === auth.uid I cannot write to the database with any user.

Comment: Nobody can create new shoe nodes with these rules, but the same applies to the rules in your question. The reason for that is that you'll want to check `newData` instead of `data` as you care about the data *after* the write operation (if that is allowed), while `data` (and `root` in your original code) are the data *before* the write operation.

Comment: I have managed to do it with this one:      `"$shoeID" : { ".write" : "data.exists() && data.child('postowner').val() === auth.uid || !data.exists() || !newData.exists()" } `. Thanks for your help!!!